# are there any polynomial-exponential, bell-shaped functions?

Tags: polynomials, function-and-relation-composition, gaussian-integral

I am looking for a polynomial-exponential, bell-shaped function under the restrictions below.

**Definition:** By polynomial-exponential function I mean something of the sort $g(x)^{h(x)}$ where $g(\cdot)$ and $h(\cdot)$ are polynomial functions with integer coefficients.

Essentially, in terms of shape, something like a Radial Basis Function, e.g. the Gaussian $\exp(-x^2)$ or the inverse quadratic $(1+x^2)^{-1}$ RBFs, going to 0 at $-\infty$ and $+\infty$, and peaking at x=0.

**RESTRICTIONS:**

- no divisions
- no non-polynomial-exponential functions (exp, log, absolute value, things requiring evaluation of logical statements,...)
- only integer coefficients (if any)
- decays to 0: $\lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x) = \lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 0$
- peaks at $x=0$ (the peak value $f(0)$ is not important)
- is symmetric around $x=0$

**RELAXATION:** (last-resort solution)

- In a last-resort case, it may be possible to work with a restricted domain, say $x \in (-10,10)$, as long as the tails are reasonably close to zero at the extremes of the domain. This is not ideal, but I may just have to fall back to it if nothing more general is available.

It does seem like a lot of restrictions but I was wondering if maybe there's something out there that I've overlooked.

Many thanks!

Comment: The only polynomial which is $0$ at $\pm \infty$ is $f(x)\equiv 0$.

Comment: A polynomial whose order depends on x :)

Comment: Maybe you can use a piecewise polynomial, something like a spline.

Comment: should have added that powers of $x$ are indeed allowed. Thanks @CountIblis

Comment: @N74 i wouldn't have thought of that. The wikipedia article gives an example, the Irwin-Hall Distribution looks bell shaped-https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)

Comment: Just note that "polynomials with degree dependent on $x$" are not polynomials. If they're fine to use that's fine, but they shouldn't be called polynomials anymore. (I'm not sure if they're strictly exponentially either; I'm not sure what they're called.)

Comment: If "degree dependent on $x$" is acceptable, could you please clarify what's wrong with the Gaussian...? (And, to second pjs36's point, a function other than a linear combination of _non-negative integer powers of $x$_ is not a polynomial. To continue to call your functions "polynomials" is to invite confusion.)

Comment: fair point @AndrewD.Hwang, but I simply don't know what a function of the type $x^x$ is called. The reason why the Gaussian is not a possibility is that I can only evaluate integers in my application. Therefore, for $x$ integer, $(11+x)^{27−x}$ would be possible to evaluate (also I've edited my other post after realising I had an "11.2" where it should be "11")

Comment: @Rahul I may just have to fall back on that as a last-resort solution. that function works great for case! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From wiki [spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)), the 'Irwin-Hall distribution'

$y=\begin{cases} 
\begin{align}
&\frac{1}{4}(x+2)^3 \quad&-2\leq x\leq-1\\
&\frac{1}{4}(3\lvert x\rvert^3-6x^2+4) \quad&-1\leq x\leq1\\
&\frac{1}{4}(2-x)^3 \quad&1\leq x\leq2\\
&\,0 \quad & \text{otherwise}
\end{align}
\end{cases}$

[image]

This seems to check all your boxes. Polynomials, it's zero outside $(-2,2)$, peaks at $x=0$, and has value $1$ there, and is symmetric about $x=0$. Thanks @N74.

Although if you count $-2\leq x\leq-1$ as evaluating a logical statement, and you don't want that, then I stand my original comment that $f\equiv0$ is the only polynomial whose limit at $\pm\infty$ is $0$.

Comment: Let's see if the OP likes it...

Comment: @N74 Fair point!

Answer (score 1):

@N74 @snulty Unfortunately, can't use inequality checking, nor absolute values. Although this comes very close and will definitely be useful in a different scenario. Thank you!

What we can do is to use polynomials with degree dependent on $x$, as @CountIblis suggested. So, something like
$$f(x) = (11+x)^{27-x}$$
seems to have roughly the right shape (slightly asymmetric, graph below) and the constants can be tweaked I guess.

**Q: Is this a known class of functions?** Perhaps they're used in some scientific field...?

It can also be written as
$$f(x) = e^{(27-x)\ln(11+x)}$$
which reveals the exponential shape.
Importantly, however, the first one is computable in the case of interest (it's enough that it works for $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $11+x>0$) while the second is not.

[image]

Comment: Simpler and symmetric: $2^{-x^2}$.

Comment: there is an implicit division there

Comment: Where?${}{}{}{}$

Comment: is there a way to compute that without performing the division $\frac{1}{2^{x^2}}$?

Comment: @pme: this was not forbidden in the statement, and disallowing negative exponents would make the question unsolvable.

Comment: @pme: the function $(11+x)^{27-x}$ does not comply with the specifications. In particular, it is undefined for $x<-11$. It also features an implicit division, which seems to be banned by the OP himself.

Comment: @YvesDaoust that was an example that would give the correct shape, and fortunately I can have bounds on $x$, say $x \in (-10,10)$ in the example and we can (possibly? haven't looked at this in detail) adjust the coefficients so that for $f(x;a,b) = (a+x)^{b-x}$ we have always $b-x>0$ and $a+x>0$, and the correct shape (this was indeed not specified, apologies).

Comment: @pme: this is not a minor change. No polynomial is bounded so all of a sudden restricting the domain is a kind of cheating.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I realise. restricting the domain is certainly not ideal but it may be a workable last-resort cheat